# Jenkins Perforce plugin failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

Just installed the latest P4 and Jenkins P4 plugin. My P4 server and client seems working well. However, I can't get it to work with Jenkins. Here is the error message below. Two problems:
1) it can't find the POM. The workspace/ directory is empty. it didn't copy anything. In the Configure page, there is an error message with the workspace "Not currently connected to a Perforce server". But my workspace is correct, and the plugin automatically detects the correct workspace name. I have attacked a snapshot please see. 
2) Email error. (I am more interested in getting the first problem resolved)[image]

```
Parsing POMs
ERROR: No such file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject/workspace/pom.xml
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?
Sending e-mails to: xxx@gmail.com
ERROR: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.execute(MailSender.java:121)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.cleanUp(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1055)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1788)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:286)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 12 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

'Not currently connected to a Perforce server' can occur if no 'Perforce Password' or 'Perforce Ticket' Credential selected.  In some old versions of the plugin there was a page refresh bug that could also cause the same error.

The POM error will occur if you are using a 'Maven Project' and there is no 'pom.xml' file in the root of your workspace.  In your case none of the Workspace fields are defined (Stream or View) and so nothing will get sync'ed to the workspace.

The question looks similar to [Perforce Jenkins view mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468528/perforce-jenkins-view-mapping/33178893#33178893), please refer to my answer regarding view mappings.