# Perforce Jenkins view mapping

Tags: jenkins, perforce

[image]

[image]
I have spent quite some time on P4 Jenkins plugin but have not been able to get it to work.

My local root directory below, which is also my workspace root directory
/home/abigail/p4/projects. My workspace name is admin_linux.

Please see my attacked P4 & P4 Jenkins plugins snapshots. I suspect my workspace mapping //depot/... //admin_linux/... may not be quite right.

After I try "build now" in Jenkins, I got this problem:

```
    Started by user gvisa
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/bword/workspace
... p4 client -o admin_linux +

P4 Task: establishing connection.
... server: x.x.x.x:1666
... node: Jenkins
... p4 info +
... p4 client -o admin_linux +
... p4 client -i +
... client: admin_linux
... p4 client -o admin_linux +
... p4 counter change +
... p4 changes -m1 //admin_linux/... +
Building on Node: master
... p4 client -o admin_linux +

P4 Task: establishing connection.
... server: x.x.x.x.:1666
... node: Jenkins

P4 Task: reverting all pending and shelved revisions.
... p4 revert /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/bword/workspace/... +
... rm [abandoned files]
duration: (22ms)

P4 Task: cleaning workspace to match have list.
... p4 reconcile -w -f /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/bword/workspace/... +
duration: (66ms)

P4 Task: syncing files at change: 26
... p4 sync -q /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/bword/workspace/...@26 +
duration: (14ms)

P4 Task: saving built changes.
... p4 client -o admin_linux +
... p4 changes -m100 //admin_linux/...@25,26 +
... p4 change -o 26 +
... p4 change -o 26 +
... p4 describe -s 26 +
... p4 fixes -c26 +
... done

Parsing POMs
ERROR: No such file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/bword/workspace/pom.xml
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?
Finished: FAILURE
```

I can see why it can't find the pom.xml, because pom.xml is ... workspace/admin_linux/bword. But how to fix this?

Comment: Is your workspace root directory really /home/abigail/p4/projects? Your console output from Jenkins shows that it is processing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/bword/workspace as the workspace root directory. Maybe the workspace that Jenkins is using is not the one you think it is.

Comment: @BryanPendleton, yes, it is, as you can see from the snapshot. I don't know how /var/lib/jenkins/jobs... is related to the workspace root directory, but my understanding is that somehow Jenkins copies the project from workspace to its own default job directory, then start to build. Isn't it? Also, I updated the complete console output.

Comment: Please add the configuration of your jenkins job in readable resolution.

Comment: It's readable on my machine. but why it doesn't after I upload to stackoverflow.  It doesn't pop up after clicking it on SO and that's why it is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins' workspace is defined by `$JENKINS_HOME`. By default that is `/var/lib/jenkins` and this is the reason why Jenkins copies stuff to that location and works there.

You can set the environment variable `$JENKINS_HOME` to your own workspace directory, if there are access problems on the predefined `/var/lib/jenkins`. However not that this is bad practice to set `$JENKINS_HOME` to a single project. Set it to a directory you own.

For setting environment variables read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session).

Comment: Should I define the $JENKINS_HOME to my workspace directory, or use the default one? I had thought the practice is to let it copy. Probably am I wrong?

Comment: I am not sure anymore if that will solve your issue. Please show us the configuration of your job.
You shouldnt set JENKINS_HOME to your project as that would have to be done for every single project, but can set it somewhere else in case of access problems. Will clarifiy that.

Comment: Added. Very simple. Please take a look.

Comment: "However note that this is bad practice", should I use the default Jenkins home directory, or change it my workspace?

Comment: Give it a try. If that solves the problem, keep looking in that direction, but keep in mind that the current solution is not good for multiple projects.

Comment: My problem is not access problem to /var/lib/jenkins.... It's a super use. It is a view mapping problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your workspace View mapping is incorrect.

You need to know the 'Depot Path' location of your POM (e.g. //depot/bword/pom.xml) you can find this easily enough using P4V and selecting the depot tab and browsing to the correct location.

The workspace maps the Depot paths (Left) to the Workspace path (right), so if you want all the files under //depot/bword/... to appear in the root of your workspace (//admin_linux/...) then your mapping will be:

```
//depot/bword/... //admin_linux/...
```

For more details on Workspace mappings take a look at the docs [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#DB5-17566) and scroll down to 'Example 2. Setting the workspace view.'